# Why is `sympy.Matrix.inv` slow?

Tags: python, matrix, sympy, symbolic-math, matrix-inverse

Here is a small example. It surprised me at how slow it is.

```py
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp

X = np.empty(shape=(10,3), dtype=object)

for i in range(10):
    for j in range(3):
        X[i,j] = sp.Symbol(f'X{i}{j}')

X = sp.Matrix(X.T @ X)
print(X.inv()) # This is really slow...
```

I would have thought that taking an inverse of a relatively small matrix would be fast. Am I missing something about the intended use case?

Comment: I think because every single term in the matrix is symbolic, this would naturally be slow. You can imagine how much trouble a human would have by calculating the inverse of a 10 x 10 matrix with each term being a variable. Each term in the inverse would probably be a very long expression. You typically do not use the inverse as is. If you are using it for solving a system of linear equations, other methods to get to the solution are faster vs. using the inverse. Then again, I do not have any real evidence and am going by intuition, but I would imagine that this is the most likely reason.

Comment: As an experiment, try starting with a small matrix (3 x 3), compute the inverse, then repeat the experiment by progressively increasing the size. I'll bet that the runtime gets larger with each increase in dimension.

Comment: The symbolic `X` is (3,3), with each term a complex 10 sum of products, right?  This isn't a simple 3x3 numeric inverse!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is your matrix:

```
In [43]: X
Out[43]: 
⎡                  2      2      2      2      2      2      2      2      2      2                                                                                                                                                                                                                     ⎤
⎢               X₀₀  + X₁₀  + X₂₀  + X₃₀  + X₄₀  + X₅₀  + X₆₀  + X₇₀  + X₈₀  + X₉₀                  X₀₀⋅X₀₁ + X₁₀⋅X₁₁ + X₂₀⋅X₂₁ + X₃₀⋅X₃₁ + X₄₀⋅X₄₁ + X₅₀⋅X₅₁ + X₆₀⋅X₆₁ + X₇₀⋅X₇₁ + X₈₀⋅X₈₁ + X₉₀⋅X₉₁  X₀₀⋅X₀₂ + X₁₀⋅X₁₂ + X₂₀⋅X₂₂ + X₃₀⋅X₃₂ + X₄₀⋅X₄₂ + X₅₀⋅X₅₂ + X₆₀⋅X₆₂ + X₇₀⋅X₇₂ + X₈₀⋅X₈₂ + X₉₀⋅X₉₂⎥
⎢                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       ⎥
⎢                                                                                                                     2      2      2      2      2      2      2      2      2      2                                                                                                                  ⎥
⎢X₀₀⋅X₀₁ + X₁₀⋅X₁₁ + X₂₀⋅X₂₁ + X₃₀⋅X₃₁ + X₄₀⋅X₄₁ + X₅₀⋅X₅₁ + X₆₀⋅X₆₁ + X₇₀⋅X₇₁ + X₈₀⋅X₈₁ + X₉₀⋅X₉₁                 X₀₁  + X₁₁  + X₂₁  + X₃₁  + X₄₁  + X₅₁  + X₆₁  + X₇₁  + X₈₁  + X₉₁                  X₀₁⋅X₀₂ + X₁₁⋅X₁₂ + X₂₁⋅X₂₂ + X₃₁⋅X₃₂ + X₄₁⋅X₄₂ + X₅₁⋅X₅₂ + X₆₁⋅X₆₂ + X₇₁⋅X₇₂ + X₈₁⋅X₈₂ + X₉₁⋅X₉₂⎥
⎢                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       ⎥
⎢                                                                                                                                                                                                                        2      2      2      2      2      2      2      2      2      2               ⎥
⎣X₀₀⋅X₀₂ + X₁₀⋅X₁₂ + X₂₀⋅X₂₂ + X₃₀⋅X₃₂ + X₄₀⋅X₄₂ + X₅₀⋅X₅₂ + X₆₀⋅X₆₂ + X₇₀⋅X₇₂ + X₈₀⋅X₈₂ + X₉₀⋅X₉₂  X₀₁⋅X₀₂ + X₁₁⋅X₁₂ + X₂₁⋅X₂₂ + X₃₁⋅X₃₂ + X₄₁⋅X₄₂ + X₅₁⋅X₅₂ + X₆₁⋅X₆₂ + X₇₁⋅X₇₂ + X₈₁⋅X₈₂ + X₉₁⋅X₉₂                 X₀₂  + X₁₂  + X₂₂  + X₃₂  + X₄₂  + X₅₂  + X₆₂  + X₇₂  + X₈₂  + X₉₂                ⎦
```

Computing the symbolic inverse of a matrix is usually not a good idea unless the matrix is very small, sparse or has some special symmetry or something. If the matrix is fully symbolic and there is no reason for the expressions in the inverse to simplify then you should expect that symbolic expressions for the inverse will be very complicated. SymPy's `inv` method will try to simplify these for you because the expression is unlikely to be much use if it cannot be simplified. That simplification is also needed in order to determine whether the matrix actually is invertible. It is the simplification part that is slow here.

If you don't want the simplification and you are happy to assume that the matrix is invertible then you can calculate an expression for the inverse quickly using the standard inverse formula:

```
In [34]: %time Xinv = X.adjugate() / X.det()
CPU times: user 543 ms, sys: 957 µs, total: 544 ms
Wall time: 543 ms
```

Even here it is only taking 0.5 seconds because `det` attempts some simplification.

I won't show the result that is returned for `Xinv` because it is enormous. Instead I'll just show how long its string representation is:

```
In [38]: len(str(Xinv))
Out[38]: 618867

In [39]: len(str(Xinv[0,0]))
Out[39]: 68219
```

Even just the first element of this matrix has a string representation that is too long to be pasted into an answer on SO.